# trying to figure out location of interrupt exit -6

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a two bag files one runs fine the other produces an error:

```
[rgbdtam-3] process has died [pid 28773, exit code -6, cmd /home/rjn/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdtam/rgbdtam /camera/rgb/image_color:=/xtion/rgb/image_raw /camera/depth/image:=/xtion/depth/image_raw __name:=rgbdtam __log:=/home/rjn/.ros/log/8047b868-c1a3-11e7-9b8b-0028f87b9f9e/rgbdtam-3.log].
log file: /home/rjn/.ros/log/8047b868-c1a3-11e7-9b8b-0028f87b9f9e/rgbdtam-3*.log
```

The bag file producing the error has its depth image as 16UC1 and the other bag has 32FC1.  I am assuming that is is what is causing the error as there are only image and depth messages in the bag files nothing else.

I tried using dbg to catch the stack trace but it does not produce one.

Does anyone know how to capture the or issue a stack trace form dbg?

thank you.

Here is output of gdb window. note line number reference given....thanks for help.

```
 V   Thread 15 "rgbdtam" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffc4b4f700 (LWP 30105)]
0x00007fffed2ff428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffed2ff428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007fffed30102a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007fffedb5b84d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fffedb596b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007fffedb59701 in std::terminate() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007fffedb59919 in __cxa_throw ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff6843cf2 in cv::error(cv::Exception const&) ()
   from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_core3.so.3.2
#7  0x00007ffff6843e83 in cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int) () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_core3.so.3.2
#8  0x00007ffff68e7c9a in cv::_OutputArray::create(int, int, int, int, bool, int) const () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_core3.so.3.2
#9  0x00007ffff6838eb9 in cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const ()
   from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_core3.so.3.2
#10 0x000000000047a3c0 in resize_points (points2=..., points=..., 
    reduction=<optimized out>, image_p=..., 
    kinect_initialization=kinect_initialization@entry=1, 
    limit_grad=limit_grad@entry=1)
    at /home/rjn/catkin_ws/src/rgbdtam/src/SemiDenseTracking.cpp:1899
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274983/trying-to-figure-out-location-of-interrupt-exit--6/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Exit code `-6` is `-SIGABRT` (see [man/signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

> Does anyone know how to capture the or issue a stack trace form dbg?

Provided you are running `rgbdtam` inside GDB (using a [launch-prefix](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) fi) *and* `rgbdtam` is a C++ node, you should just be able to `bt <enter>` after GDB has caught the crash.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-11-06**:
did that ... but did not produce trace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Then I think we're going to need much more information: please show us how you ran the node in GDB exactly (ie: copy-paste from your terminal and / or launch file). More info about the node, any command sequences you used, etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Additionally (but I've no way of knowing whether you already did that): make sure you've performed a debug build of the package/workspace. Without that, GDB will not be able to find any symbols, making any backtrace much less informative.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-11-06**:
I ran with
launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"
in launch file....and compiled with set debug.  Got some output in gdb window but but can not seem to copy it ., other wise I would update question.
Still not a full stack trace .... as to where in node call is .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
Select the output in the terminal, right mouse button -> copy, or `ctrl+shift+c`. Then `ctrl+v` in your question text (*edit* it), select it, press *Preformatted Text* button (`101010`).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-06**:
O wait, you're running in an `xterm`. Then it's a little different. See [ask ubuntu/How does copy-paste work with xterm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm).

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2017-11-06**:
you can copy and past by selecting text in xterm, then simutaiously pressing the left and right enter keys
Ive updated the question .. problem resolved.